# how to limit the amount of comments or replies to comments a user can post per day

Tags: php, limit, insert-query

I have a comment section and a reply to comment section on my social network. We are having some trouble with manual spammers, and I was going to limit the amount of comments someone could post a day.

Here are the insert queries for comments and reply to comments:

```
//COMMENTS

$query = "INSERT INTO `CysticAirwaves` ( 
                                        `FromUserID`,
                                        `ToUserID`,
                                        `comment`,
                                        `status`,
                                        `statusCommentAirwave`,
                                        `date`,
                                        `time`

                                ) VALUES (

                                    '" . $auth->id ."',
                                    '" . $prof->id ."',
                                    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ProfileComment']) ."',
                                    'active',
                                    'active',
                                    '" . date("Y-m-d") . "',
                                    '" . date("G:i:s") . "')";
    mysql_query($query,$connection); 

    if($auth->id == $prof->id) {
        $just_inserted = mysql_insert_id();
        $query = "UPDATE `CysticAirwaves` SET `status` = 'dead' WHERE `FromUserID` = '" . $auth->id . "' AND `ToUserID` = '" . $prof->id . "' AND `id` != '" . $just_inserted . "'";
        $request = mysql_query($query,$connection);
}

//REPLIES

$query = "INSERT INTO `CysticAirwaves_replies` (
                                    `AirwaveID`,
                                    `FromUserID`,
                                    `comment`,
                                    `status`,
                                    `date`,
                                    `time`
                                ) VALUES (
                                    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']) . "',
                                    '" . $auth->id . "',
                                    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply']) . "',
                                    'active',
                                    '" . date("Y-m-d") . "',
                                    '" . date("G:i:s") . "'
                                    )";
    mysql_query($query,$connection);

    $mailto = array();

    /* get the person that wrote the inital comment */
    $query = "SELECT `FromUserID` FROM `CysticAirwaves` WHERE `id` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']) . "' LIMIT 1";
    $request = mysql_query($query,$connection);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $comment_author = new User($result['FromUserID']);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a select to see how many entries are in the table already by that user for the current date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   CysticAirwaves
WHERE  userid = $auth->id
  AND  date = CURDATE()
```

Then only perform the `INSERT` if the number is below your threshold. Alternatively, you can place a trigger on the `INSERT` that does this check with every `INSERT` and bounces the call as well. ("Best practice" would be to place it in the database as this would be a database-related limitation, but that's your call)

**It's been a while** since I've done MySQL triggers, but I *think* think is what you're after:

```
delimeter |

CREATE TRIGGER reply_threshold BEFORE INSERT ON CysticAirwaves_replies
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE reply_count INT;
    SET reply_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CysticAirwaves_replies WHERE userid = NEW.userid AND `date` = CURDATE());
    IF reply_count > 5 THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Too many replies for today';
    END IF;
  END;

|
delimeter ;
```

Essentially, if you go to insert a reply in the table and the threshold has been exceeded, a sql error will be raised stopping the action. You can't "prevent" an insert per-say, but you can raise an exception that makes it fall-through.

Answer (score 1):

You can only limit this by the ip address when you don't have a login system. But the ip can change and this is here the problem.

The best way is to secure the form by a login. That only user can post when they are logged in.

Last technique is to use a captcha like [Recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php) then at most time bots fill out your form and spam to your system.

When you have a login. Then make a table related to your usertable and count the INSERTS. Before you INSERT a new comment check the table if there was a INSERT today.

Answer (score 1):

Before to insert the comment, you check if the user has posted more than 5 comments in the day.
If yes, you don't insert the comment and you display a message.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CysticAirwaves_replies WHERE FromUserID = the_user_id AND date = CURDATE()
```

Comment: so I would put that before the insert query, and than after it do something like "if(COUNT(*)) < 5 {} wrapped around the insert query?

Answer (score 1):

Besides counting before each insertion, you can store the number of comments made by an user somewhere directly, so you don't have to do the count(*) every time (which can be expensive if an user has lots of comments and the table you have is somewhat big).

Like, on commenting:

```
SELECT comment_count FROM comment_count_table WHERE user_id = ?
```

If that value is small enough, you do:

```
UPDATE comment_count_table SET comment_count = comment_count + 1 WHERE user_id = ?
```

Be careful with this since you'd need to reset that counter somehow.
At my company we implemented this setting a "last modified field". When we do the SELECT, if the "last modified day" is not today, then we reset the counter.

Another option is to have a cron job that resets the counter for all users once every day, but that is way too expensive.